# Circular Dependency Error - baking AO Texture

Tags: texturing

Blender 2.93 trying to bake AO Textures.

Baked a couple of objects OK then the following error was presented: Circular Dependency for image "Body_AO_2" from object rear_door_generic

Any ideas on how to solve it - it has become a huge pain and cannot figure how to fix it. Images attached of the node setup.

[image: blender log]

[image: node setup]

https://ibb.co/s5kXyGz

https://ibb.co/X5ZWrN6

Answer (score 2):

The error message tries to tell you that you cannot bake a texture to an image and use that image at the same time to determine the color that you want to bake.

The solution is to disconnect the *Image Texture* node of the bake target (*Body_AO_2*) while you bake. Make sure the image is not used in other materials.

After you baked the image you can reconnect the *Image Texture* node. Don't forget to save the image. It's not saved with the blend file (except you pack it).